# How do I store a functions output without re-running the function in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Essentially I have 2 functions, the second takes in the output of the first as a parameter. Something like:

```
value1 = function1()
value2 = function2(value1)
```

I want to avoid running the first since it takes a long time to run (5mins+). In jupyter notebook you can just comment out the first line and it will run no problem, but in Spyder it says value1 is not defined. Is there any way to do this in spyder?

Comment: Just run the function once, print `value1`, then comment out the first line and simple add something like `value1 = 42` or whatever the result of function1 is.

Comment: alternatively, for more complex data, you can store your result in a text file and make the function2 dig the data from the file

Comment: I should have added that value1 is actually a pretty large dataframe. But I was hoping that there would just be a quick way like in Jupyter. I will write it to a pkl/txt instead. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is the perfect case for [code cells](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/editor.html#defining-code-cells), which are blocks of code that you can evaluate independently.

For that you need to create a cell between `value1` and `value2` by adding a comment like this between them:

```
value1 = function1()

# %%

value2 = function2(value1)
```

Then you can run the cell that contains `value1` only once by putting the cursor there and pressing `Shift+Enter`. Afterwards, you can modify the contents of the second cell and run it as many times as you want with `Shift+Enter`, without evaluating `value1` again.